# How can i correctly store Jar libs outside WebSphere?

Tags: java, websphere, websphere-7, filenet-p8, filenet

I want to have my EventHandlers stored in custom folder, instead of CodeModule.
I have WebSphere 7.0, so i set ClassPath value for JVM as "C:\jar" (without brackets), and put my Test.jar there. Now i want to create EventAction without CodeModule defined, but I stil have "Unable to load event handler class from either associated code module or system classpath:" error, what am i doing wrong?

Solved!
 It's important to set individual filepath for every .jar (like "C:\jar\Test.jar").

Comment: If you found a solution, you should post the answer and accept it.

Comment: Setting the JVM classpath is not recommended for general purpose JARs: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/info/ae/ae/urun_rconfproc_jvm.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that keeping code modules outside WebSphere is not quite good idea, because you should restart it's service every time you change module. I found great plugin for Eclipse [here](http://www.ecmdeveloper.com/) that do all work about CodeModules.